# How to create a column in a Dataframe that calculates cross_val_score based on values from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, linear-regression, k-fold

I created a `DataFrame` (`df_kfolds`) with 2 columns: `kfolds` & `Mean_Score` where `Kfolds` has values ranging from 3 to 5. I'm trying to calculate the `mean_score` of each kfold derived from the following:

```
cross_val_score(lr, X, y, cv=3, error_score = 1).mean()
```

where :

```
lr = LinearRegression()
X are the feature variables
y is the target
cv = # of kfolds
```

I know you can create columns based on simple mathematical calculations with values from another column but not sure if you can use statistical functions. Here's my code :

```
df_kfolds['Mean_Score'] = cross_val_score(lr, X, y, cv=(df_kfolds['kfolds']), error_score = 1).mean()
```

throwing this error :

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Thanks for any help on this!

Comment: Can you provide a minimum example with some sample data that one could run?

Comment: Your error message implies (complete stacktrace would reveal more) that there's a comparison of a "column" (Series) happening as part if-condition somewhere in your code (a Series contains many values, so the if condition cannot decide which path to take as the condition may be true for some values, but not for all). Without more information (stacktrace, example) it's hard to give more advice.